# App screenshots gets blurry after uploading to Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-console

I've made a simple android application and have published on Google Play Store, everything seems to be working good but, the screenshots of app that I'm uploading gets blurry on Play Store, even though the real image looks good.

I found some similar question on SO, but none of them really helped me.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914040/10767715), I tried uploading 480x800 image but that too didn't worked, the image still looks blurry.

There was one more answer according to which We should upload `PNG` image because `JPEG` images can easily be compressed, but I'm already using `PNG` images.

I've googled a lot but found nothing.

Take this image for example,This image is what I'm uploading to Play Store, This looks sharp but on Play Store, the text of this images get blurry.

[image: Screenshot Sample]

And see how blurry it makes the image:

[image: Blurred Image]

[Link to Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coolgame.zlytherin.game.tic_tac_toe) So that you can see images getting blurred. *Try using mobile device, blurriness can be seen easily on that, and on full-screen blurriness gets increased.*

Now, Please help me so that I can post good looking image on Play Store and the image does not gets blurry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186193/discussion-between-sahdeep-singh-and-zathura).

Comment: Hey @Zathura, I compared the images on the Play Store and the provided original one. It seems similar to me! Also the Play store one is better than the original image :)

Comment: @Gourav, Check out on mobile and edited question as well

Comment: Use a PNG image rather than JPEG.

Comment: @Pierre, thanks for your comment, but are you sure that you've read the whole question?

Comment: Apparently not, sorry :x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand. When viewing screenshots through the browser, they are displayed in their original format and quality. And when viewing screenshots via Google Play, they are always compressed, and png is also compressed. So try to download screenshots in jpeg format in maximum quality. Also use the screenshots of the maximum resolution, according to the rules of Google, one of the side can not be more than 3840 px, so try using screenshots for example 2160x3840 px. It partially helped me to improve the quality.

Comment: Thanks bud, It worked! :D Now the image quality is much more better than before!