# google play store makes screenshots low qualities because of compression

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

[Screenshots for my app are badly compressed when viewed in the Play Store app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60259173/screenshots-for-my-app-are-badly-compressed-when-viewed-in-the-play-store-app)

[App screenshots gets blurry after uploading to Google Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039422/app-screenshots-gets-blurry-after-uploading-to-google-play-store)

I took screenshots with the screenshot feature in Android Studio, the device was 2460 x 1440. I checked the screenshots after release. When I look at the Google Play Store screenshot on the desktop, it is perfect, but when I go to the url with a smartphone and check it, the quality is 10 times worse. The gradation is all dirty and spread in layers.

my app`s background color is gradient so can not be changed to solid color.

Is there any way to solve this?

---

I tried 2160 x 3840 also (PNG, JPG) and nothing changed

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question

Answer (score -1):

I guess there is no way to solve this problem

I am chaning background color because of this for moments

what a ridiculous

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819103/cannot-remove-google-play-release-error-how-do-i-tell-google-play-that-my-app-i