# Cannot remove Google Play Release error. How do I tell Google Play that my app isn't for COVID tracing?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm trying to create an Internal Testing Release of a new app, and on the Releases Review page, it says there is 1 error. When I expand that error, it says:

"Error. You must let us know whether your app is a COVID-19 contact tracing or status app."

There is no instruction of how to say my app isn't about COVID, and I can't find anywhere in the Play Developer UI where I can say whether or not the app is a COVID app.

My app is in the music category, so it's not like it's medical or anything.

Any idea how to remove this error? I've been hunting around for hours!

Comment: prolly you should remove permissions which makes google think that your app is "COVID-19 contact tracing or status app" ... [which are not know to us as we are not google customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions)

Answer (score 20):

Was experiencing the same issue.

1. Go into your app in the Google Play Console.
2. Search for "App Content", click on it.
3. At the top there should be a Covid-19 contact tracing and status
   apps questionnaire.

3.1 If there is not, try disabling ad-blockers, as I was using Brave browser shields and it was not appearing.

Comment: Thank you so much! I searched everywhere for this.
This cannot be found anywhere on the left navigation area in the console and the error message does not help at all.
Such horrible UX.

Comment: This was missing on my Play Store. I had to refresh, because I believe I was having this issue on the exact day they rolled out the feature?